# java maximum value of string after split

Tags: java, sorting, split, max

I'm taking beginner's java course and I have this kind of task:

User inputs word + number, for example, "animal" + "age":

*horse:3* 
*dog:5*
*parrot:2*
*cat:7*

I have to make the program to print out the age of the oldest animal. 
For example like this:

*The age of the oldest animal is: 7*

Now, this is what I have written so far. My problem is that I don't know how to make the program compare the numbers...

```
    while (true) {

        String luettu = x.nextLine();   // user inputs animals and numbers
        if (dataIn.equals("")) {        // when inputs nothing program stops
            break;
    }
        // Here I separate the animal and number with star symbol
        String[] separatedData = dataIn.split(":"); 

        // From now on, I'm supposed to focus on the numbers, create the rule for how to find the highest value

        x = x Integer.valueOf(separatedData[1]);  // Must target the values in the index 1 (the numbers)  but how?
    }
    int maxNumber = separatedData.lenght; 
    int i = 0;

    // I don't know how to loop and compare the numbers... and I thin "while" doesn't make sense here
    while ( i < size of separatedData) {
        if(maxNumber < separatedData) {
            maxNumber = separatedData;
        }
    System.out.println("The age of the oldest animal is: " + maxNumber); // printing the result
```

So half of the code is a mess and I'm stuck.
Please help me and if you can give explanations, that would be great, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding the maximum of something, set the max to the smallest value possible.  That would be

```
maxAge = Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Then set a string variable like this.

```
String oldestAnimal = "";
```

Now as  you loop thru the values, compare the `current age` to `max`.  If age is larger, set
`max to age` and set `oldestAnimal to the animal` associated with that age.

The compare would be like:

```
if (age > max) {
   // set appropriate values.
}
```

When you are done,  you will have the results.

Comment: Even though OP's requirement does not mention printing the name of the animal, this answer does it nicely. +1